# Why does gtm.js scripts set _gcl_au cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gdprconsentform

I am trying to deal with GDPR and to clear all the cookies, which must be cleared from the cite.
RN I found out, that `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=[MY_ID]` sets `_gcl_au` cookie what is uniq id for the client as far as I see in the `gtm.js` code:

In the internet there are said that `_gcl_au` cookie is used for "Conversion Linker" functionality or Google AdSense functionality:
[link to the question](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/6211471/what-is-the-cookie-gcl-au-used-for?hl=en)

Moreover, `gtm.js` includes code injecting `fbevents`/`crazy-egg`/`gstatic` scripts on my cite: [print screen of code injection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEJTb.png)

But the only tag I'm using is a `Google Analytics`. I've found how to disable `GA` if a user doesn't accept Analytical data using.

But how to stop injecting additional scripts and `_gcl_au` cookie?

I don't thing that whole deleting of the `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=[MY_ID]` is a solution

Is it possible to do in a dev way?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer?

Comment: We use https://github.com/brainsum/cookieconsent to block this (and other) cookies. The `_gcl_au` cookie can then be blocked using their script tag method. Might that be an option for you?